dynamo.updateItem(...).promise is not a function
I'm referring to the CDK tutorial here https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/40-hit-counter/200-handler.html
but my code below
await dynamo.updateItem({
    TableName: process.env.HITS_TABLE_NAME,
    Key: { path: { S: event.path } },
    UpdateExpression: 'ADD hits :incr',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':incr': { N: '1' } }
}).promise();

will return this error dynamo.updateItem(...).promise is not a function. It seems the tutorial is outdated.. what should I change to fix the code?

It's outdated yes, Lambdas runtime now includes JavaScript SDk V3 but your coding for V2.
If you're using the V3 JavaScript SDK then the updateItem returns a promise by dead.
Here's an example
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, UpdateCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

...
...


await ddbDocClient.send(
      new UpdateCommand({
        TableName: "RetailDatabase",
        Key: {
          pk: "jim.bob@somewhere.com",    // Partition key
          sk: "metadata",                 // Sort key
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#n": "name",
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set #n = :nm",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":nm": "Big Jim Bob",
        },
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
      })
  );

